# angular 5 with gridster having different components

Tags: angular, layout, angular5, angular-material2, gridster

i am using angular 5 with latest material and trying to get gridster working from https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2

My html looks like:

```
 <gridster [options]="options">
                        <gridster-item [item]="item" *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
                              <app-infolet-smart-alerts [ngClass]="(smartAlertState == false) ? 'dashboard-widget-1-2' : 'dashboard-widget-2-2'" 
                                                            (onClickedExpand)="smartAlertSize($event)">
                              </app-infolet-smart-alerts>

                        </gridster-item>
                  </gridster>
```

the relevant .ts

```
ngOnInit() {

     this.options = {
       itemChangeCallback: DynamicHomeComponent.itemChange,
       itemResizeCallback: DynamicHomeComponent.itemResize,
       draggable: {
         enabled: true
       }
     };

     this.dashboard = [
       {cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 1, x: 1},
       {cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 1, x: 1}
     ];
  }

options: GridsterConfig;
dashboard: Array<GridsterItem>;
```

**Questions**
1. what is y and x here? assuming cols and rows are number of col out of 12 the individual item is gonna take.

2. i have like different components as it's a dashboard. let's say defined as  `<app-comp1></app-comp1>`  and `<app-comp2></app-comp2>` So, how is my grid going to render 1st comp in 1st item and 2nd comp in 2nd item of the grid?  it's not list of images that i can pass as array based on some index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glance at the code in the gridster github repo, I believe that cols and rows is for the objects size/representation. The y and x are the axis's of which the object will be placed in the grid.

```
<gridster [options]="options">
  <gridster-item [item]="{cols: 2, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 0}">
    <app-comp1></app-comp1>
  </gridster-item>
  <gridster-item [item]="{cols: 2, rows: 1, y: 3, x: 4}">
     <app-comp2></app-comp2>
  </gridster-item>                  
</gridster>
```

Comment: Think I might have miss understood your second question. You could look into ngcomponentoutlet as well. https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Comment: i m more confused with your response about 2nd question. i already have 10 compoenents then why i need this dynamic component rendering etc.? to simply lets say i want to render a mat-button in one cell, a mat-icon in another rather mat-button or mat-icon in all the cells. so how will that work?

Comment: Instead of looping I would suggest generating each grid item separately that way you can customize everyone